# C++ Animating a button with MoveWindow()

Tags: c++, animation, winapi, window

I am new to C++ and seem to be stuck. I basically have a Window and a Button inside it(also created with CreateWindow()). I want to have the button moving on the X axis, I tried doing with MoveWindow() but I cant seem to do the animation effect. I tried writing it in a for loop but I have not found what to use to delay the animation. I would appreciate any help.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
     MoveWindow(g_MovingDot, i, ButtonTop, ButtonWidth, ButtonHeight, true);
     //Delay it somehow
}
```

Would this be the right way to do it? I just want the button to move slowly to the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`SetTimer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644906%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) function to be notified when the time-out value is elapse.

Implement a function with the signature

```
VOID (CALLBACK* TIMERPROC)(HWND, UINT, UINT_PTR, DWORD);
```

and pass a function pointer to `SetTimer`, to register a callback procedure .

Use a global control variable, which controls the animation of the window. In the following code snippet the control variable is named `i_g`.
When the timer is elapsed, then the callback procedure is called. Increment the control variable, slightly move the dialog element and restart the timer, until the final position is reached.
The animation time is controlled by the number of animation steps and the time interval of a single step.

```
int g_i=0;

void CALLBACK BtnTimer( HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, UINT_PTR idEvent, DWORD dwTime )
{
    KillTimer( hwnd, idEvent );
    if ( g_i < 50 )
    {
      MoveWindow(g_MovingDot, i, ButtonTop, ButtonWidth, ButtonHeight, true);
      g_i ++;
      SetTimer( hwnd, idEvent, 100 /* time milliseconds */, &BtnTimer );
    }
}

void AnimateButton( HWND hDialogWnd //* HWND from Dialog */)
{
    g_i = 0;
    SetTimer( hDialogWnd, 0 /* idEvent */, 100 /* time milliseconds */, &BtnTimer );    
}
```